# rails display the records list in index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I need to display all the customer in a index page in a csv format.

```
 def self.customer_list
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |customer_detail|
      csv << customer_detail.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end
 end


 def index
    @customer_details = CustomerDetail.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @customer_details.customer_list }
    end
  end
```

The problem is the page is redirecting to the index page.But it did not show the records in the index page.It shows an empty index page.I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: you need to add .csv at the end of url. e.g /customers.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 def index
    @customer_details = CustomerDetail.customer_list
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @customer_details }
    end
  end
```

Hope it will help.